# How to list unused AWS S3 buckets and empty bucket using shell script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, sh, aws-cli

I am looking for list of unused s3 buckets from last 90 days and also for empty bucket list.

In order to get it, I have tried writing code as below:

```
#/bin/sh
for bucketlist in  $(aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name");
do
  listobjects=$(\
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketlist \
    --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `2020-08-06`)]')
done
```

This code prints following output: [I have added results for only one bucket for reference]

```
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "test2/image.png",
            "LastModified": "2020-08-06T17:19:10.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"xxxxxx\"",
            "Size": 179008,,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expectations:**

1. In above code I want to print only bucket list which objects are not modified/used in last 90 days.
2. I am also looking for empty bucket list

I am not good in programming, Can anyone guide me on this?
Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: This type of task would be much easier with a language (eg Python) rather than using shell because the code would need to examine the results of the queries.

Comment: what you are looking for? the complete program?

Comment: yes help in program

Comment: you could use python boto3 which is the best way to handle aws components. you can also check this article which explains the same. [How do I see which S3 buckets are empty?](https://medium.com/@alannewcomer/how-do-i-see-which-s3-buckets-are-empty-76cdbb67da86)

Answer (score 4):

I made this small bash script to find empty buckets in my account:

```
#!/bin/zsh
for b in $(aws s3 ls | cut -d" " -f3)
do
  echo -n $b
  if [[ "$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $b --max-items 1)" == "" ]]
  then
    echo " BUCKET EMPTY"
  else
    echo ""
  fi
done
```

I listed the objects using the list-objects-v2 with maximum items of 1. If there are no items - the result is empty and I print "BUCKET EMPTY" alongside the bucket name.

- Note 1: You must have access to list the objects.
- Note 2: I'm not sure how it'll work for versioned buckets with deleted objects (appears to be empty, but actually contains older versions of deleted objects)

---

This works well but doesn't consider the non-current version objects. For that you can use "list-object-versions" then it will look for non-current version objects as well.

#!/bin/zsh
for b in $(aws s3 ls | cut -d" " -f3)
do
echo -n $b
if [[ "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $b --max-items 1)" == "" ]]
then
echo " <----- BUCKET EMPTY"
else
echo ""
fi
done

Comment: You are right in your "note 2". This does not examine if previous versions of deleted objects exist. If you need to delete the whole bucket, it needs to be emptied of current and previous versions before deletions can occur.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script I wrote today.  It doesn't change anything, but it does give you the commandlines to make the changes.

```
#!/bin/bash
profile="default"
olddate="2020-01-01"
smallbucketsize=10

emptybucketlist=()
oldbucketlist=()
smallbucketlist=()

#for bucketlist in  $(aws s3api list-buckets  --profile $profile  | jq --raw-output '.Buckets[6,7,8,9].Name'); # test this script on just a few buckets
for bucketlist in  $(aws s3api list-buckets  --profile $profile  | jq --raw-output '.Buckets[].Name');
do
  echo "* $bucketlist"
  if [[ ! "$bucketlist" == *"shmr-logs" ]]; then
    listobjects=$(\
      aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketlist \
      --query 'Contents[*].Key' \
      --profile $profile)
#echo "==$listobjects=="
    if [[ "$listobjects" == "null" ]]; then
          echo "$bucketlist is empty"
          emptybucketlist+=("$bucketlist")
    else
      # get size
      aws s3 ls --summarize  --human-readable --recursive --profile $profile s3://$bucketlist | tail -n1

      # get number of files
      filecount=$(echo $listobjects | jq length )
      echo "contains $filecount files"
      if [[ $filecount -lt $smallbucketsize ]]; then
          smallbucketlist+=("$bucketlist")
      fi

      # get number of files older than $olddate
      listoldobjects=$(\
        aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucketlist \
        --query "Contents[?LastModified<=\`$olddate\`]" \
        --profile $profile)
      oldfilecount=$(echo $listoldobjects | jq length )
      echo "contains $oldfilecount old files"

      # check if all files are old
      if [[ $filecount -eq $oldfilecount ]]; then
        echo "all the files are old"
        oldbucketlist+=("$bucketlist")

      fi
    fi
  fi
done
echo -e "\n\n"

echo "check the contents of these buckets which only contain old files"
for oldbuckets in ${oldbucketlist[@]};
do
  echo "$oldbuckets"
done
echo -e "\n\n"

echo "check the contents of these buckets which don't have many files"
for smallbuckets in ${smallbucketlist[@]};
do
  echo "aws s3api list-objects --bucket $smallbuckets --query 'Contents[*].Key' --profile $profile"
done
echo -e "\n\n"

echo "consider deleting these empty buckets"
for emptybuckets in "${emptybucketlist[@]}";
do
  echo "aws s3api delete-bucket --profile $profile --bucket $emptybuckets"
done
```